# Heroku Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I'm currently trying to put an app on heroku and I keep getting this error, any thoughts?

I added the Procfile in order to make heroku run my app cause I am not using npm start. On my machine it only raises a warning,but I have no clue what can be the cause of this.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903231+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35:41)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903233+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903233+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903234+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903234+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903235+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903236+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:16:13)
    2017-04-17T13:55:16.903236+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    2017-04-17T13:56:39.858509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=invoices-app.herokuapp.com request_id=de360abf-f350-4dca-87ce-af98e458f270 fwd="79.117.186.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2017-04-17T13:56:40.477926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=invoices-app.herokuapp.com request_id=9d310798-59aa-42cb-87a5-3ff8ab3f2fef fwd="79.117.186.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "apache-server-configs": "^2.11.0",
    "chai": "^2.1.0",
    "connect": "^3.3.4",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.8",
    "gulp-csso": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.0.4",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-jscs": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.2",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-ngdocs": "^0.2.10",
    "gulp-plumber": "^0.6.6",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.3",
    "gulp-size": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^1.1.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.1",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "lazypipe": "^0.2.2",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.1.0",
    "mock-gulp-dest": "^0.1.1",
    "opn": "^1.0.1",
    "serve-index": "^1.6.2",
    "serve-static": "^1.9.1",
    "wiredep": "^2.2.2",
    "yargs": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: do you use any outdated version of any modules? or some module which showing WARN on your system is causing the issue. Try switching to previous version of that module.

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since this was posted but I thought I would help any others having this issue.

Gulp tends to fail when your karma is out of date.

You currently have version `0.12.31` the current version of karma at the time of this post is `1.7.0`

The solution is easy, just run:

```
npm install karma@latest
```